# Django/postgresql: DETAIL: Failing row contains (43, , 1, 2016-01-02, 31, null, null)

Tags: django, postgresql

***I am attempting to submit a comment like so...***

```
Comment.objects.create(content = comment, post = post, user = request.user)
```

***When I do this I am getting the following error...***

```
IntegrityError at /addcomment/1
null value in column "commentnumber" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (43, , 1, 2016-01-02, 31, null, null).
```

The two 'nulls' that are failing non null constraints are previous fields named`commentnumber` and `commentcount` in the `Comment` model that I later deleted by deleting the migrations file and then using `makemigrations` and `migrate` to save the changes.

Why am I still required to enter information into to `commentnumber` and `commentcount` when they are clearly deleted?

If any more information is needed, please ask in the comments. I would be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The two 'nulls' that are failing non null constraints are previous
>   fields namedcommentnumber and commentcount in the Comment model that I
>   later deleted by deleting the migrations file and then using
>   makemigrations and migrate to save the changes.

Deleting the migrations files does **not** remove the fields from your database tables. You must run the migration backwards to do that first. *In that case, running the migration forward add the fields so backwards remove them.*

For example if you add the field `comments.comment_number` in migration 38. First run `./manage.py migrate your_app 37`. This will remove the column `comment_number` from the table. In other words, your database is now in the "state" 37. You can now remove the migration file 38.

As you have already removed your migration files and you know what columns should be removed, you better do it manually (via Postgres) but keep in mind the above "technique" for next time :)

---

If you want to know more, look at the source code, open up your migration, you can see it extends `migrations.Migration`. Have a look at that class, the method you are looking for is: `unapply`.

Comment: How would I go about deleting it via postgresql?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? No offence but just Google that question "delete column in postgres".

Comment: Today I got the same error with spring-boot and spring-jpa. The same error due to renaming the model class variable which is annotated with @NotNull. I have to manually remove old columns from the database to fix the issue. Thanks for your answer +1